# SELECT and UPDATE multiple records in oriento / orientjs and transaction in waterline

Tags: database, sails.js, orientdb, waterline, sails-orientdb

How can I select or update multiple records in oriento? Like in waterline we can

```
offersModel.update({id:items_ids,status:INACTIVE},{status:ACTIVE})
```

But in waterline transaction is not available. So I want to use  :

```
var db = offersModel.getDB();
var trans = db.begin();
    trans.update('offers')
         .set({status:INACTIVE})
         .where({id:items_ids,status:ENM.SELLING_STATUS.ACTIVE})//.exec()
         .then(function(offers){ 
            if  (offers.length != items_ids.length) {trans.rollback(); /* send error here*/} 
            else trans.commit();
         })
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Dário no one is replying this question. Is that question is not meaningful ?

Comment: Hi @9me, perhaps the Oriento folks don't hang out here, you can also try [Oriento gitter channel](https://gitter.im/codemix/oriento) and the [Oriento project](https://github.com/codemix/oriento). Regarding your example: `.where({id:items_ids,status:ENM.SELLING_STATUS.ACTIVE}).exec()`, you don't need an `.exec()` before a `.then(/*...*/)`.

Comment: @Dário Thank you for reply. my sorry I can not explain my use-case. My use-case is  `begin() then update items then  **if any item is missing** rollback() else commit()` How can I perform this transaction ?

Comment: @9me: did you fix it? Shouldn't you use the `scalar()` function like [in this example](https://github.com/codemix/oriento#user-content-query-builder-update-record)

Answer (score 4):

Try this

db.update(id).set({status:INACTIVE}).scalar()

Comment: What about multi ids and transaction. In case of fail how can I undo this transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following?

```
db.update(id).set({status:INACTIVE}).scalar()
```

Comment: I did not tried it yet but my question is about mostly related with transaction based on more then one classes.